# How to specify block gasLimit for hardhat node

Tags: hardhat, nodes

When starting local ganache blockchain I am able to specify block gasLimit for the network.

Example:

```
 ganache-cli --gasLimit=60000000
```

I tired to do same with hardhat node

```
npx hardhat node --gasLimit==60000000
```

But that doesn't seem to work, so I hope someone here knows the way around this.

Comment: npx hardhat node --gasLimit==60000000 why == ?

Comment: I haven't seen any example where you can give args to "npx hardhat node"

Comment: I just started using it, so I was experimenting. As far as I can see, I need to go to hardhat.config.js and set the block gasLimit there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it by setting the blockGasLimit value inside hardhat.config.js

```
require("hardhat-tracer");
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");


/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {

  defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
  networks: {
      hardhat: {
          blockGasLimit: 60000000 // Network block gasLimit
      },
  },

  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.3",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 2**32-1,     // Optimized for SmartContract usage, not deployment cost.
      },
    },
  },

};
```

Comment: good idea ……